# Kendo grid float type

Tags: c#, kendo

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.EngineModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Название").Width(170);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Type).Title("Тип").Width(170);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Power).Title("Мощность").Width(170);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Volume).Title("Объем").Width(170);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(220).Title("Операции");
  })
  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .PageSize(20)
      //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(p => p.Id);
      })
      .Create(update => update.Action("Engine_Create", "Auto"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("Engine_Read", "Auto"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Engine_Update", "Auto"))
      .Destroy(update => update.Action("Engine_Destroy", "Auto"))
  )

public class EngineModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Название двигателя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Тип двигателя")]
        public string Type { set; get; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Мощность двигателя")]
        public int Power { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Объем двигателя")]
        public float Volume { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Engine_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, EngineModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
            {
                EngineCommand.Create(Context).EngineCreate(model);
            }
            return Json(new[] {model}.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

Допустим при добавлении объема двигателя ввожу 1.9 то на контроллер приходит 0.0. Пробовал менять тип float и double одинаковая ерунда. В чем дело?

Comment: Изменил вот так:.Create(update => update.Action("Engine_Create", "Auto").Data("convertDecimals"))
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertDecimals(data) {
        for (var property in data) {
                var value = data[property];
                if (typeof value === "number") {
                    if (value % 1 == 0) {
                        data[property] = value.toString();
                    } else {
                        data[property] = kendo.toString(value, "n");
                    }
                }
        }
    };
</script>

Comment: public JsonResult Engine_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IEnumerable<EngineModel> arrEngineModels = EngineQueries.Create(Context).GetAllEngine();
            //return Json(arrEngineModels.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(arrEngineModels.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: Данные не загружаются. но при нажатии на Добавить появляется вот такое: {"Data":[{"Name":"q2","Type":"w","Power":1,"Volume":21,"Id":5},{"Name":"q","Type":"w","Power":1,"Volume":2,"Id":6}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}